# I can't run my code builded in notebook in computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I use OneDrive in my notebook and computer and salve the codes there. But when I need to run some code built in the notebook in computer, it can't for some errors.

e.g:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "errno.h"   Inicio  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\cerrno  7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "float.h"   Inicio  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\cfloat  7   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "corecrt.h" Inicio  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\crtdefs.h   10  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "stddef.h"  Inicio  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\cstddef 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Windows SDK as well.